# Hadoop fsck command

Tags: hdfs

I got the IP of where my data blocks are stored through fsck command under "DatanodeInfoWithStorage":

```
$ hadoop fsck /user/aaa/file.name -files -locations -blocks
```

this command lists the below information:

```
[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP1,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP2,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP3,DISK]]
```

However, I would like to know how to trace the path of the file under each IP of the data nodes.

Comment: $ hadoop fsck /user/aaa/file.name -files -locations -blocks this command and it listed the below information
 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP1,DISK], 
DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP2,DISK], 
DatanodeInfoWithStorage[DatenodeIP3,DISK]]